# How to read an attribute tag with an equals sign from XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

I'm parsing an XML file through Java, and am able to parse through Nodes in the XML file that appear as:

`<name><given>familyName</given></name>`

by using code such as the snippet shown below:

```
NodeList givenElmntLst = firstElement.getElementsByTagName("given");
Element givenNmElmnt = (Element) givenElmntLst.item(0);
NodeList fstNm = givenNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
String given = ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue();
```

but I am unable to read attributes that are formatted as such:

```
<birthTime value="19230101"/>
```

How should I be reading values such as the one above differently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `getAttribute()` ?

Comment: What do you mean you are unable to read them? Do you get an exception or is it that you just can't get the String "19230101"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i'm assuming your using the `org.w3c.dom` package...

try something like this:

```
NodeList birthTimeLst = firstElement.getElementsByTagName("birthTime");
Element birthTime = (Element) birthTimeLst.item(0);
String value = birthTime.getAttribute("value");
```